# How to add a new column to a hierarchical dataframe grouped by groupby

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

The following script try to calculate the resulting average of the direction and magnitude of the wind. My monthly dataframe has the following column:

```
data

Fecha            Hora    DirViento  MagViento Temperatura  Humedad  PreciAcu    
0   2011/07/01  00:00        318        6.6        21.22      100       1.7    
1   2011/07/01  00:15        342        5.5        21.20      100       1.7    
2   2011/07/01  00:30        329        6.6        21.15      100       4.8    
3   2011/07/01  00:45        279        7.5        21.11      100       4.2   
4   2011/07/01  01:00        318        6.0        21.16      100       2.5
```

The first thing I do is convert to radians the DirViento column

```
dir_rad=[]
for i in range(0, len(data['DirViento'])):
    dir_rad.append(data['DirViento'][i]*(pi/180.0))
data['DirViento']=around(dir_rad,1)
```

Now get the columns of the components: u and v wind and add to data

```
Uviento=[]
Vviento=[]
for i in range(0,len(data['MagViento'])):
    Uviento.append(data['MagViento'][i]*sin(data[DirViento][i]))
    Vviento.append(data['MagViento'][i]*cos(data[DirViento][i]))
data['u']=around(Uviento,1)   
data['v']=around(Vviento,1)  


data
Data columns:
Fecha           51  non-null values
Hora            51  non-null values
DirViento       51  non-null values
MagViento       51  non-null values
Temperatura     51  non-null values
Humedad         51  non-null values
PreciAcu        51  non-null values
u               51  non-null values
v               51  non-null values
dtypes: float64(6), int64(2), object(2)
```

Now we indexed the dataframe and grouped

```
index=data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'],inplace=True)

grouped = index.groupby(level=0)

data['u']

Fecha       Hora 
2011/07/01  00:00    -4.4
            00:15    -1.7
            00:30    -3.4
            00:45    -7.4
            01:00    -4.0
2011/07/02  00:00    -4.5
            00:15    -4.2
            00:30    -7.6
            00:45    -3.8
            01:00    -2.0
2011/07/03  00:00    -6.3
            00:15   -13.7
            00:30    -0.3
            00:45    -2.5
            01:00    -2.7
```

Now get resultant wind direction for each day

```
 grouped.apply(lambda x: ((scipy.arctan2(mean(x['uu']),mean(x['vv'])))/(pi/180.0)))

 Fecha
 2011/07/01   -55.495677
 2011/07/02   -39.176537
 2011/07/03   -51.416339
```

The result obtained, I need to apply the following conditions

```
for i in grouped.apply(lambda x: ((scipy.arctan2(mean(x['uu']),mean(x['vv'])))/(pi/180.0))):
    if i < 180:
        i=i+180
    else:
        if i > 180:
            i=i-180
        else:
            i=i
    print i

124.504323033
140.823463279
128.5836605
```

How to add the previous result to the next dictionary

```
stat_cea = grouped.agg({'MagRes':np.mean,'DirRes':np.mean,'Temperatura':np.mean,'Humedad':np.mean,'PreciAcu':np.sum})



stat_cea
Fecha        DirRes     Humedad          PreciAcu  Temperatura

2011/07/01             100.000000          30.4      21.367059              
2011/07/02             99.823529           18.0      21.841765    
2011/07/03             99.823529            4.0      21.347059
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own aggregate functions to apply to grouped data https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964938/2530083.  So for your case you could try something like:

```
import numpy as np

def DirRes(group):
    u=np.sum(group['MagViento'] * np.sin(np.deg2rad(group['DirViento'])))
    v=np.sum(group['MagViento'] * np.cos(np.deg2rad(group['DirViento'])))
    magres=np.sqrt(u*u+v*v)    

    magdir=np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(u,v))
    if magdir<180:
        magdir+=180
    elif magdir>180:
        magdir-=180

    return magdir


def MagRes(group):
    u=np.sum(group['MagViento'] * np.sin(np.deg2rad(group['DirViento'])))
    v=np.sum(group['MagViento'] * np.cos(np.deg2rad(group['DirViento'])))
    return np.sqrt(u*u + v*v)
```