# Aggregate Dataframe into weighted average series

Tags: python, pandas

This might be a complicated task. Say we have a dataframe like this:

```
MSFT   AAPL   GE
0.1     na    na
0.2     0.1   na
0.1     0.2   0.1
```

I want to aggregate the dataframe as follows:

Whenever there is only one column with non-na value, that value will be the avg, but when more than one column with non-na value, we calculate the weighted average where the weight is the cumulative product up to this point. The resultant dataframe and calculation is as illustated below.

```
avg
0.1
1.1*0.2/(1.1 + 1) + 1*0.1/(1.1+1)
1.1*1.2*0.1/(1.1*1.2+1.1+1) + 1.1*0.2/(1.1*1.2+1.1+1)+ 1*0.1/(1.1*1.2+1.1+1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your DataFrame is named 'd'
Try this:

```
d.mean(axis=1)
```

That should work.

Comment: Hey, This only takes the equal weighted average, not the weighted average scheme as I described.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951341/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-function-using-multiple-columns) then. That might help.