# function in groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by

I would like to calculate a mean value of "bonus" according to column "first_name", but the denominator is not the sum of the cases, because not all the cases have weight of 1, instead the may have 0.5 weight.

for instance in the case of Jason the value that I want is the sum of his bonus divided by 2.5.

Since in real life I have to group by several columns, like area, etc, I would like to adapt a groupby to this situation.

Here is my try, but it gives me the normal mean

```
raw_data = {'area': [1,2,3,3,4],'first_name': ['Jason','Jason','Jason', 'Jake','Jake'],
        'bonus': [10,20, 10, 30, 20],'weight': [1,1,0.5,0.5,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['area','first_name','bonus','weight'])
df
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate weighted average using a pandas/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205922/calculate-weighted-average-using-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
(df.groupby('first_name')[['bonus', 'weight']].sum()
  #.add_prefix('sum_') # you could also want it
   .assign(result = lambda x: x['bonus'].div(x['weight'])))
```

or

```
(df[['first_name', 'bonus', 'weight']].groupby('first_name').sum()
  #.add_prefix('sum_')
   .assign(result = lambda x: x['bonus'].div(x['weight'])))
```

**Output**

```
            bonus  weight     result
first_name                          
Jake           50     1.5  33.333333
Jason          40     2.5  16.000000
```

Comment: just one thing. here it works perfectly, but in real life I have several columns and this code add results column, but also a lot of columns that I don't want to the df dataframe. here for example now I addes an "area" column, and you could see in the output an aggregated column with the sum of area. is there a way to avoid this area column in the results?

Comment: you can select columns after or before groupby, please see updated code:)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `groupby().apply` and `np.average`:

```
df.groupby('first_name').apply(lambda x: np.average(x.bonus, weights=x.weight))
```

Output:

```
first_name
Jake     23.333333
Jason    14.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is looking for *for instance in the case of Jason the value that I want is the sum of his bonus divided by 2.5.*, but good answer:)

Comment: @Quang Hoang I think that there is something wrong in your code, the correct aimed results are shown by ansev answer

Comment: My code computes **weighted average**, not entirely what you want, which is want @ansev does.