# Remove quotation marks and brackets from Pandas DataFrame .csv file after performing a GroupBy with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, export-to-csv

I'm new to pandas so apologies if my explanations of things are wrong.

I have a data frame created as follows:

```
        arrays = [array1, array2]
        index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names = ("name1", "name2"))
        df = pd.DataFrame({"name3": array3, "name4": array4}, index=index)
```

Then I perform a weighted mean, using the indices, using code from the second top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205922/calculate-weighted-average-using-a-pandas-dataframe).

```
        df2 = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.name3, weights=x.name4))
        print(df2)
```

The output on the console looks like this:

```
        (1, 2) 3
        (4, 5) 6
        (7, 8) 9
```

where (x,y) are the indices that I have grouped by and the number at the end is the weighted mean.

When I export to a .csv file, I get a file that looks like this:

```
        ,0
        "(1, 2)",3
        "(4, 5)",6
        "(7, 8)",9
```

This is not what I want. I would like to get a .csv file that looks like this:

```
        name1,name2,avg
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9
```

I've tried using reset.index() but this does not work. I want to remove the brackets, quotation marks and the rogue ,0 at the start of the .csv file. How can I do this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data?

Comment: @Roy2012 I have added some sample data now, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I see you got an answer ... great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) level instead of indices:

```
df2 = df.groupby(level=df.index.names).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.name3, weights=x.name4))

# save the df2 to csv file
df2.rename('avg').reset_index().to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I have another question, if you don't mind answering - how could I also calculate the error on the weighted mean and make this another column? The error is calculated as err = 1/sum(weights)

Comment: @JoeBarnes We can use `df2 = df.groupby(level=df.index.names).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.average(x.name3, weights=x.name4), 1/x.name4.sum()], index=['avg', 'err']))
`

Comment: @JoeBarnes Also, you don't need `.rename` anymore since now we have specified names in the series itself.