# Weighted average by another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the average score of every group in a column weighted by another column.

I will write an example to clarify my goal. Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe:

| Group | # items | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 2 |
| A | 15 | 4 |
| A | 20 | 6 |
| B | 5 | 5 |
| B | 10 | 8 |

My desired output would be:

| Group | avg_weighted_score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4.444 |
| B | 7 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',10,2],['A',15,4],['A',20,6],['B',5,5],['B',10,8]],columns = ['Group', '#items', 'score'])
```

Comment: so `#Item` is the weighted column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate weighted average using a pandas/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205922/calculate-weighted-average-using-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do this:

```
f = lambda x: sum(x['#items'] * x['score']) / sum(x['#items'])

df.groupby('Group').apply(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Group the dataframe by `Group` column, then apply a function to calculate the weighted average using `nump.average` passing `score` column values for average, and `# items` as weights. You can call `to_frame` passing new column name to create a dataframe out of the resulting sereis.

```py
(
    df.groupby('Group')
    .apply(lambda x: np.average(x['score'], weights=x['# items']))
    .to_frame('avg_weighted_score')
    )
       avg_weighted_score
Group                    
A                4.444444
B                7.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel you get better performance if you precompute the sum of the product of the weighted columns, before grouping and aggregating (just an assumption):

```py
(df.set_index('Group')
   .assign(numerator = lambda df: df.prod(1))
   .groupby('Group')
   .pipe(lambda group: group.numerator.sum() / group['#items'].sum())
)


Group
A    4.444444
B    7.000000
dtype: float64
```

Another solution, from @Mozway:

```py
groups = (df.assign(w=df['#items']
                      .mul(df['score']))
           .groupby(df['Group']) 
         )

groups['w'].sum().div(groups['#items'].sum())

Group
A    4.444444
B    7.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Damn I was wondering why I got the wrong answer, I used the wrong column ^^. Here is a version similar to what you did (+1 btw), but using groupby objects directly (if you want feel free to use in your answer): `groups = df.assign(w=df['#items'].mul(df['score'])).groupby(df['Group']) ; 
groups['w'].sum().div(groups['#items'].sum())`. This should indeed be faster than the `apply` approaches

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby("Group")
    .apply(lambda x: np.average(x["score"], weights=x["#items"]))
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "avg_weighted_score"})
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Group  avg_weighted_score
0     A            4.444444
1     B            7.000000
```