# I want to groupby add a weighted average and then new column into the new groubpy dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to create a pandas pivot table but looking to create a weighted average next to the MTD Rate. I was also able to create a weighted average doing multiple formulas, just learning how to do this.  The weighted avg are correct so now trying to combine into a nice single dataframe.

Essentially, I am want to get an weighted avg price by taking using the total shares by trader which is predicated based based on a share weight by strategy.  From there I am taking the weight x MTD Rate and the sumtotal is the weighted average price.

Any assistance is very helpful.   My code for pandas pivot:[image]

My code for weighted avg is below in a new dataframe

[image]

Where I am trying to get to is below:

[image]

Comment: Please see [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and avoid all screenshots of data/code/errors.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

Build a data frame from your means.

```
meanR = *yourFunction*.reset_index() \
    .rename(columns={"MTD rate": "MTD weighted mean"})
finalR = df.merge(meanR)
```

The Python function used here for computing weighed means will often not perform as well or be as accurate as a Numpy function. There is one provided here: [Calculate weighted average using a pandas/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205922/calculate-weighted-average-using-a-pandas-dataframe)