# Combine complex aggregation function when using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Think of the following table

```
np.random.seed(42)
ix = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-15', freq='60s')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'val': np.random.random(size=ix.shape[0]),
        'active': np.random.choice([0,1], size=ix.shape[0])
    },
    index=ix
)
df.sample(10)
```

yielding:

```
                    active   val
2017-01-02 06:05:00 1   0.774654
2017-01-04 08:15:00 1   0.934796
2017-01-13 01:02:00 0   0.792351...
```

My objective is to compute:

- sum per day
- sum of actives per day

**Sum per day** This one is straightforwards:

```
gb = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index.date))
overall_sum_per_day = gb['val'].sum().rename('overall')
```

**Sum per active day** This is a little trickier (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964938/671013)).

```
active_sum_per_day = gb.agg(lambda x: x[x.active==1]['val'].sum())['val'].rename('active')
```

**My question** How can I combine the two. Using `concat`:

```
pd.concat([overall_sum_per_day, active_sum_per_day], axis=1)
```

I can achieve my objective. But I fail to do achieve it in one go and apply the two aggregations at once. Is it possible? See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951341/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-function-using-multiple-columns#comment47838830_10964938).

Comment: Check my answer to see how you can clean up your groupby and applying function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
b = gb.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x['val'].sum(), x.loc[x.active==1, 'val'].sum()], 
                                  index=['overall', 'active']))
print (b)
               overall      active
2017-01-01  715.997165  366.856234
2017-01-02  720.101832  355.100828
2017-01-03  711.247370  335.231948
2017-01-04  713.688122  338.088299
2017-01-05  716.127970  342.889442
2017-01-06  697.319129  338.741027
2017-01-07  708.121948  361.086977
2017-01-08  731.032093  370.697884
2017-01-09  718.386679  342.162494
2017-01-10  709.706473  349.657514
2017-01-11  720.477342  368.407343
2017-01-12  738.286682  378.618305
2017-01-13  735.805583  372.039108
2017-01-14  727.502271  345.612816
2017-01-15    0.613559    0.613559
```

Another solution:

```
b = gb.agg(lambda x: [x['val'].sum(), x.loc[x.active==1, 'val'].sum()])
       .rename(columns={'val':'overall'})
print (b)
                active     overall
2017-01-01  715.997165  366.856234
2017-01-02  720.101832  355.100828
2017-01-03  711.247370  335.231948
2017-01-04  713.688122  338.088299
2017-01-05  716.127970  342.889442
2017-01-06  697.319129  338.741027
2017-01-07  708.121948  361.086977
2017-01-08  731.032093  370.697884
2017-01-09  718.386679  342.162494
2017-01-10  709.706473  349.657514
2017-01-11  720.477342  368.407343
2017-01-12  738.286682  378.618305
2017-01-13  735.805583  372.039108
2017-01-14  727.502271  345.612816
2017-01-15    0.613559    0.613559
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC we can do it in one step, working with your original DF:

```
In [105]: df.groupby([df.index.normalize(), 'active'])['val'] \
     ...:   .sum() \
     ...:   .unstack(fill_value=0) \
     ...:   .rename(columns={0:'overall', 1:'active'}) \
     ...:   .assign(overall=lambda x: x['overall'] + x['active'])
Out[105]:
active         overall      active
2017-01-01  715.997165  366.856234
2017-01-02  720.101832  355.100828
2017-01-03  711.247370  335.231948
2017-01-04  713.688122  338.088299
2017-01-05  716.127970  342.889442
...                ...         ...
2017-01-11  720.477342  368.407343
2017-01-12  738.286682  378.618305
2017-01-13  735.805583  372.039108
2017-01-14  727.502271  345.612816
2017-01-15    0.613559    0.613559

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```

Explanation:

```
In [64]: df.groupby([df.index.normalize(), 'active'])['val'].sum()
Out[64]:
            active
2017-01-01  0         349.140931
            1         366.856234
2017-01-02  0         365.001004
            1         355.100828
2017-01-03  0         376.015422
                         ...
2017-01-13  0         363.766475
            1         372.039108
2017-01-14  0         381.889455
            1         345.612816
2017-01-15  1           0.613559
Name: val, Length: 29, dtype: float64

In [65]: df.groupby([df.index.normalize(), 'active'])['val'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[65]:
active               0           1
2017-01-01  349.140931  366.856234
2017-01-02  365.001004  355.100828
2017-01-03  376.015422  335.231948
2017-01-04  375.599823  338.088299
2017-01-05  373.238528  342.889442
...                ...         ...
2017-01-11  352.069999  368.407343
2017-01-12  359.668377  378.618305
2017-01-13  363.766475  372.039108
2017-01-14  381.889455  345.612816
2017-01-15    0.000000    0.613559

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: you should use .assign with a lambda rather than eval, which is a bit magical

Comment: @Jeff, OK, thanks for the comment! I'll change it as soon as I'm back on my notebook (writing from my phone)

Comment: @Jeff, using `assign` - how would I access dynamically created columns?

Comment: @jeff This is a problem where this [resample.apply](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15169) bug crops up

Answer (score 1):

I think it's cleaner to do the grouping with `pd.Grouper` which is built for datetime grouping. Also you can define a function for clarity.

```
def func(df):
    active = (df['active'] * df['val']).sum()
    overall = df['val'].sum()
    return pd.Series(data=[active, overall], index=['active','overall'])

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).apply(func)

                active     overall
2017-01-01  366.856234  715.997165
2017-01-02  355.100828  720.101832
2017-01-03  335.231948  711.247370
2017-01-04  338.088299  713.688122
2017-01-05  342.889442  716.127970
2017-01-06  338.741027  697.319129
2017-01-07  361.086977  708.121948
2017-01-08  370.697884  731.032093
2017-01-09  342.162494  718.386679
2017-01-10  349.657514  709.706473
2017-01-11  368.407343  720.477342
2017-01-12  378.618305  738.286682
2017-01-13  372.039108  735.805583
2017-01-14  345.612816  727.502271
2017-01-15    0.613559    0.613559
```

You should be able to perform this operation with `resample` and `apply` but [there is a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15169).

```
df.resample('d').apply(func) # should work but doens't produce correct output           

                active  val
2017-01-01  366.856234  NaN
2017-01-02  355.100828  NaN
2017-01-03  335.231948  NaN
2017-01-04  338.088299  NaN
2017-01-05  342.889442  NaN
2017-01-06  338.741027  NaN
2017-01-07  361.086977  NaN
2017-01-08  370.697884  NaN
2017-01-09  342.162494  NaN
2017-01-10  349.657514  NaN
2017-01-11  368.407343  NaN
2017-01-12  378.618305  NaN
2017-01-13  372.039108  NaN
2017-01-14  345.612816  NaN
2017-01-15    0.613559  NaN
```