# How to groupby dataframe with categorical variables for making linechart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-manipulation

I have time series dataframe for product transaction history, I need to make linechart in order to see product shipper's cost trend. To make plotting dataframe, I need to groupby marketing threshold which is categorical variables and use weighted average function for `avergage_cost_threshold`. I came up weighted average function and tried to group them for making plotting data but seems I made wrong manipulation on my data, resulted plotting dataframe is giving error. I tried of using `apply` function `pandas.groupby` but couldn't get correct structured plotting data? Can anyone point me out possible idea to make this right? Any thoughts?

**my current attempt**:

here is my attempt in [this colab](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/8bd29300c52dd2a5642c1ef8eb5c5c89) and here is [example_df](https://jmp.sh/v/VmgYTj7UHA4Ca1DVGjmL) that I tried in my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('timeseries_df.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

# calculate comparable cost by using average threshold
def weighted_average(df, data_col, weight_col, by_col):
    df['_data_times_weight'] = df[data_col] * df[weight_col]
    df['_weight_where_notnull'] = df[weight_col] * pd.notnull(df[data_col])
    g = df.groupby(by_col)
    result = g['_data_times_weight'].sum() / g['_weight_where_notnull'].sum()
    del df['_data_times_weight'], df['_weight_where_notnull']
    return result

## for example, for Alpha Food Corps, all 50 threshold of protein with corresponding quantity_received, we'd get average threshold; 
df_new = df.groupby(['dealer', 'threshold', 'protein_type'])['threshold']
df_new['avg_threshold'] = df_new.groupby(['dealer']).apply(wavg, "threshold", "quantity_received")  ## some issue with this grouping
df_new['comparable_cost'] = df['price']*76/ df_new['avg_threshold']
```

basically, I want to find average threshold by using threshold and quantity_received, and above `weighted_average` will do this. But in my attempt I got wrong plotting dataframe.

for example, in my example dataframe, I want to see proportion of each different threshold in each different dealer along the time. To see dealer' cost dynamic in linechart, I need to find average threshold for each dealer then find its comparable cost value as new column. In ideal plotting dataframe, I want to see all dealer's cost dynamic (i.e, price, comparable cost) w.r.t each `protein_type` in each threshold along time series. Probably, there might be easier way to aggregate my dataframe and generate meaningful time-series linechart. I am open to hear possible approach, suggestion to deal with this question. Thanks

**update**

In line-chart, I want to see proportion of each `protein_type` in certain `threefold` for all dealer's cost dynamic along the time. Basically, I want to see which dealer has better response to the market and so on. Can anyone point me out which way is the best to deal with this sort of EDA practice in python? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1: `df_new = df.groupby(['dealer', 'threshold', 'protein_type'])['threshold']`

- This line is the first issue. `df_new` is a `SeriesGroupBy object`

  - Each group contains `['threshold']` data for `['dealer', 'threshold', 'protein_type']`
- Each group looks like:

```py
('Cargill', 50, 'chicken')
1013    50
1056    50
1089    50
1161    50
1207    50
Name: threshold, dtype: int64
```

### 2: `df_new['avg_threshold'] = df_new.groupby(['dealer']).apply(wavg, "threshold", "quantity_received")`

- `df_new.groupby(['dealer'])` results in `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'groupby'`

  - This occurs because `df_new` is a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`
  - `['dealer']` doesn't exist in the `Series`
- Inside the `weighted_average` function, another groupby is performed.

  - Update the initial groupby with all relevant columns to end up with

    - `df.groupby(['dealer', 'threshold'])`
- With the original groupby, `df_new['avg_threshold'] = df_new.groupby(['dealer']).apply(wavg, "threshold", "quantity_received")`

  - Change `df_new.` to `df.`
  - Properly apply the function `.apply(wavg, "threshold", "quantity_received")`

    - The function is `weighted_average`, not `wavg`.
    - In addition to the DataFrame, the function requires 3 parameters, but only 2 have been provided.

      - However, we're going to drop `by_col` from the function
  - The updated groupby and function call will be:

    - `dfg = df.groupby(['dealer', 'threshold']).apply(weighted_average, 'price', 'Quantity Received')`

### 3

#### a: Update `def weighted_average`

- Is from [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683506)
- Remove `by_col` and `g = df.groupby(by_col)`
- Instead of assigning the final calculation to `result` and returning result

  - Assign the calculation to `df['weighted_average']`
- Return the updated DataFrame with the calculations

```py
# calculate comparable cost by using average threshold
def weighted_average(df, data_col, weight_col):
    df['_data_times_weight'] = df[data_col] * df[weight_col]
    df['_weight_where_notnull'] = df[weight_col] * pd.notnull(df[data_col])
    df['weighted_average'] = df['_data_times_weight'].sum() / df['_weight_where_notnull'].sum()
    df = df.drop(columns=['_data_times_weight', '_weight_where_notnull'])
    return df
```

#### b:

- This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964938) is cleaner
- 3a and 3b produce the same result

```py
def weighted_average(group, price, weight):
    d = group[price]
    w = group[weight]
    group['weighted_average'] = (d * w).sum() / w.sum()
    return group
```

### 4: Updated Code

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the data
df = pd.read_csv('data/so_data/2020-08-03 63239708/mydf2.csv', parse_dates=['date'])

# calculate comparable cost by using average threshold
def weighted_average(df, data_col, weight_col):
    df['_data_times_weight'] = df[data_col] * df[weight_col]
    df['_weight_where_notnull'] = df[weight_col] * pd.notnull(df[data_col])
    df['weighted_average'] = df['_data_times_weight'].sum() / df['_weight_where_notnull'].sum()
    df = df.drop(columns=['_data_times_weight', '_weight_where_notnull'])
    return df


# call the function
dfg = df.groupby(['dealer', 'threshold']).apply(weighted_average, 'price', 'Quantity Received')

# display(dfg.head())
        date              dealer  threshold  Quantity Received  price  Freight  dealer_delivered_cost  Freshness_Days protein_type  tot_distance destination  weighted_average
0 2017-12-22  Golden State Foods         50              39037    0.5     0.07                    0.6            3.39      chicken         901.0          US          0.839475
1 2017-12-27  Golden State Foods         85              35432    1.8     0.07                    1.9            3.39         beef         901.0          US          1.950728
2 2017-12-29  Golden State Foods         50              32142    0.5     0.07                    0.6            3.39      chicken         901.0          US          0.839475
3 2017-12-30  Golden State Foods         85              34516    1.8     0.07                    1.9            3.39         beef         901.0          US          1.950728
4 2018-01-02  Golden State Foods         85              39930    1.8     0.07                    1.9            3.39         beef         901.0          US          1.950728
```

### 5: Shape the DataFrame and plot

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

# set threshold as a category
dfg.threshold = dfg.threshold.astype('category')
# set the index
dfg = dfg.set_index(['date', 'dealer', 'protein_type', 'threshold'])

# form the dataframe into a long form
dfl = dfg[['weighted_average', 'price']].stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4': 'cats', 0: 'values'})
```

#### plot with all dealers

```py
markers = {"price": "s", "weighted_average": "X"}

for pt in dfl.protein_type.unique():
    for t in dfl.threshold.unique():
        data = dfl[(dfl.protein_type == pt) & (dfl.threshold == t)]
        if not data.empty:  # for some thresholds there's no data
            utc = len(data.threshold.unique())
            f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=utc, ncols= 1, figsize=(20, 7), squeeze=False)
            for j in range(utc):
                p = sns.scatterplot('date', 'values', data=data, hue='dealer', markers=markers, style='cats', ax=axes[j, 0])
                p.set_title(f'Threshold: {t}\n{pt}')
                p.set_xlim(data.date.min() - timedelta(days=60), data.date.max() + timedelta(days=60))
                plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc="center left", borderaxespad=0)
            plt.show()
```

- First two plots with all dealers
  [image]

#### plot with separate dealers

- Within each group, `weighted_average` is one value. Instead of plotting it as part of `cats`, plot it as a single horizontal line, using [`plt.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html)

```py
ud = dfl.dealer.unique()
date_min = dfl.date.min()
date_max = dfl.date.max()

for pt in dfl.protein_type.unique():
    for t in dfl.threshold.unique():
        data = dfl[(dfl.protein_type == pt) & (dfl.threshold == t)]
        if not data.empty:  # for some thresholds there's no data
            utc = len(data.threshold.unique())
            f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=utc, ncols= len(ud), figsize=(30, 5), squeeze=False)
            for j in range(utc):
                for i, d in enumerate(ud):
                    data_d = data[data.dealer == d].sort_values(['cats', 'date']).reset_index(drop=True)
                    price = data_d[data_d.cats == 'price']
                    w_avg = data_d[data_d.cats == 'weighted_average']
                    p = sns.scatterplot('date', 'values', data=price, hue='cats', ax=axes[j, i])                    
                    
                    if not data_d.empty:  # for some thresholds there is no data for dealer d in this loop
                        p.hlines(w_avg['values'].unique().tolist(), w_avg.date.min(), w_avg.date.max(), 'orange', label='weighted avg')
                        p.set_title(f'{d}\nThreshold: {t}\n{pt}')
                        p.set_xlim(date_min - timedelta(days=60), date_max + timedelta(days=60))
                        p.legend().set_visible(False)
                        labels = [datetime.fromordinal(int(v)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for v in p.get_xticks()]
                        p.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
                    else:
                        p.set_title(f'{d}: No Data Available\nThreshold: {t}\n{pt}')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,0.5), loc="center left", borderaxespad=0)        
    plt.show()
```

- First couple of rows
  [image]

#### one column of plots

- Iterate through each unique combination of values for `protein_type`, `threshold`, and `dealer`

```py
up = dfl.protein_type.unique()
ud = dfl.dealer.unique()
ut = dfl.threshold.unique()
date_min = dfl.date.min()
date_max = dfl.date.max()
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')

for pt in up:
    for th in ut:
        for dl in ud: 
            data = dfl[(dfl.protein_type == pt) & (dfl.threshold == th) & (dfl.dealer == dl)]
            if not data.empty:  # for some thresholds there's no data
                price = data[data.cats == 'price']
                w_avg = data[data.cats == 'weighted_average']
                fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
                p = sns.scatterplot('date', 'values', data=price, hue='cats', ax=ax)
                p.hlines(w_avg['values'].unique().tolist(), w_avg.date.min(), w_avg.date.max(), 'orange', label='weighted avg')
                p.set_title(f'{dl}\nThreshold: {th}\n{pt}')
                p.set_xlim(date_min - timedelta(days=60), date_max + timedelta(days=120))

                p.set_xticklabels(p.get_xticks(), rotation=90)
                p.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
                
                plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0)        
                plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, thanks very much! Hope you enjoy your riding :).

Comment: @Trenton McKinney this is much helpful for dealing with time series data, well done!